# Can someone help me identify the bike frame?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, paint, restoration

I have had this frame for a while now and I would like to restore it to its original look.

The person who sold it to me said that its a Sintezi, but that sounds wrong to me, all I know about it that it has Reynolds 501 chrommoly M tubing.

Also I would like to ask what would be the proper way to restore and repaint a frame like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pretty  generic, and you managed to miss important details in your photos.  A shot of the area around the rear axle would be helpful, as well better photos in the area of the brakes.  As it is, probably late 70s through late 80s, medium quality.

Comment: Pic of headtube badge would be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply's, and excuse my inexperience i hope that these set of pictures will work better.